# API is being called twice when using feature module Angular 8

Tags: angular8

As per Angular documentation, I have done the following steps.

1. Added `CommonModule` in the Feature Module(not `BrowserModule`).
2. Used `ProvidedIn: 'root'`

Here is what I have done so far.

**AppModule**

```
import { BrowserModule, Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatStepperModule } from '@angular/material/stepper';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatCheckboxModule } from '@angular/material/checkbox';
import { MatDatepickerModule } from '@angular/material/datepicker';
import { MatRadioModule } from '@angular/material/radio';
import { MatSelectModule } from '@angular/material/select';
import { MatSlideToggleModule } from '@angular/material/slide-toggle';
import { MatMenuModule } from '@angular/material/menu';
import { MatSidenavModule } from '@angular/material/sidenav';
import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material/toolbar';
import { MatCardModule } from '@angular/material/card';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { MatProgressBarModule } from '@angular/material/progress-bar';
import { MatDialogModule } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { MatSnackBarModule } from '@angular/material/snack-bar';
import { MatPaginatorModule } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { MatSortModule } from '@angular/material/sort';
import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material/table';
import { MatListModule } from '@angular/material/list';
import {
  MatNativeDateModule,
  MatAutocompleteModule
} from '@angular/material';
import { MatProgressSpinnerModule } from '@angular/material/progress-spinner';
import { MatGridListModule } from '@angular/material/grid-list';
import { MatChipsModule } from '@angular/material/chips';
import { MatExpansionModule } from '@angular/material/expansion';
import { MatTabsModule } from '@angular/material/tabs';
// import { AppraisalModule } from './feature-modules/yearly-appraisal/appraisal.module';

import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { SensitiveService } from './services/sensitive.service';
import { ErrorService } from './classes/error';
import { UserService } from './services/user.service';
import { ExcelService } from './services/excel.service';
import { AuthGuard } from './auth.guard';
import { ProjectService } from './services/project.service';
import { InterviewService } from './services/interview.service';
import { KickoffService } from './services/kickoff.service'

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './dashboard/auth/login/login.component';
import { ForgotPasswordComponent } from './dashboard/auth/forgot-password/forgot-password.component';
import {
  UserComponent,
  // DialogAddUserComponent,
  DialogDeleteUserComponent,
  DialogChangeStatusComponent
} from './dashboard/user/user.component';
import { ViewComponent } from './dashboard/view/view.component';
import { CreatePasswordComponent } from './dashboard/auth/create-password/create-password.component';
import {
  ToolbarComponent,
  DialogLoaderComponent
} from './dashboard/shell/toolbar/toolbar.component';
import { SideNavComponent } from './dashboard/shell/side-nav/side-nav.component';
import { FilterComponent } from './dashboard/filter/filter.component';
import { CandidateListComponent } from './dashboard/candidate-list/candidate-list.component';
import { CandidateFiltersComponent } from './dashboard/candidate-filters/candidate-filters.component';
import { LoaderDownloadComponent } from './dialogs/loader-download/loader-download.component';
import { AdvancedFiltersComponent } from './components/advanced-filters/advanced-filters.component';
import { ProjectAddComponent } from './components/projects/project-add/project-add.component';
import { ProjectListComponent } from './components/projects/project-list/project-list.component';
import { LoaderComponent } from './dialogs/loader/loader.component';
import { ErrorComponent } from './dialogs/error/error.component';
import { SuccessComponent } from './dialogs/success/success.component';
import { ConfirmationComponent } from './dialogs/confirmation/confirmation.component';
import { MatDividerModule } from '@angular/material/divider';
import { AgoPipe } from './pipes/ago.pipe';
import { TimeAgoPipe } from 'time-ago-pipe';
import { MoveProjectComponent } from './dialogs/move-project/move-project.component';
import { CandidateService } from './services/candidate.service';
import { MatTooltipModule } from '@angular/material/tooltip';
import { RemoveApplicantComponent } from './dialogs/remove-applicant/remove-applicant.component';

import { NgxMatSelectSearchModule } from 'ngx-mat-select-search';
import { InterviewListComponent } from './components/interviews/interview-list/interview-list.component';
import { MoveInterviewComponent } from './dialogs/move-interview/move-interview.component';

import { NgxMaterialTimepickerModule } from 'ngx-material-timepicker';
import { InterviewStatusComponent } from './dialogs/interview-status/interview-status.component';
import { HrComponent } from './components/hr/hr.component';
import { AssignHrComponent } from './dialogs/assign-hr/assign-hr.component';
import { HrService } from './services/hr.service';
import { LoiComponent } from './dialogs/loi/loi.component';
import { OfferLetterComponent } from './dialogs/offer-letter/offer-letter.component';
import { FinalStepComponent } from './dialogs/final-step/final-step.component';
import { FeedbackComponent } from './components/feedback/feedback.component';
import { InterviewFeedbackShowComponent } from './dialogs/interview-feedback-show/interview-feedback-show.component';
import { InterviewerProfileComponent } from './components/interviewer-profile/interviewer-profile.component';
import { AddInterviewerComponent } from './components/add-interviewer/add-interviewer.component';
import { RecruitmentSummaryFiltersComponent } from './components/recruitment-summary-filters/recruitment-summary-filters.component';
// import { InterviewRoundTwoComponent } from './dialogs/interview-round-two/interview-round-two.component';
// import { InterviewRoundTwoFeedbackComponent } from './dialogs/interview-round-two-feedback/interview-round-two-feedback.component';
// tslint:disable-next-line:max-line-length
// import { InterviewRoundTwoFeedbackShowComponent } from './dialogs/interview-round-two-feedback-show/interview-round-two-feedback-show.component';
import { MatRippleModule } from '@angular/material/core';
import { SideNavLatestComponent } from './components/side-nav-latest/side-nav-latest.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './shell/footer/footer.component';
import { JobPostingComponent } from './components/job-posting/job-posting.component';
import { JobPostingCreateComponent } from './components/job-posting-create/job-posting-create.component';
import { CKEditorModule } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular';
import { AssignProjectComponent } from './dialogs/assign-project/assign-project.component';
import { CarouselModule } from 'ngx-owl-carousel-o';
import { NodataComponent } from './utilities/nodata/nodata.component';
import { ScreeningComponent } from './utilities/screening/screening.component';
import { EngagedViewComponent } from './dialogs/engaged-view/engaged-view.component';
import { RejectLoiComponent } from './dialogs/reject-loi/reject-loi.component';
import { MoveApplicantComponent } from './dialogs/move-applicant/move-applicant.component';
import { DialogExampleComponent } from './dialogs/dialog-example/dialog-example.component';
import { MakeJobLiveComponent } from './dialogs/make-job-live/make-job-live.component';
import { DragDropModule } from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';
import { VerifyDocumentsComponent } from './dialogs/verify-documents/verify-documents.component';
import { CheckDocumentsComponent } from './components/check-documents/check-documents.component';
import { SuggestOfferComponent } from './hr/suggest-offer/suggest-offer.component';
import { AddUserComponent } from './dashboard/add-user/add-user.component';
import { EditUserComponent } from './dashboard/edit-user/edit-user.component';
// import { ChangeStatusComponent } from './dashboard/edit-user/edit-user.component';
// import { ChartsModule, ThemeService } from 'ng2-charts';
//import { AppraisalProgressComponent } from './components/appraisal-progress/appraisal-progress.component';
// import { UpdateEmpMappingComponent } from './dialogs/update-emp-mapping/update-emp-mapping.component';
import { BottomSheetComponent } from './dialogs/bottom-sheet/bottom-sheet.component';
//import { ScheduleMeetingComponent } from './dialogs/schedule-meeting/schedule-meeting.component';
//import { EmployeeSefComponent } from './dialogs/employee-sef/employee-sef.component';
//import { AppraisalIssueShowComponent } from './dialogs/appraisal-issue-show/appraisal-issue-show.component';
// import { SefFeedbackFormComponent } from './dialogs/sef-feedback-form/sef-feedback-form.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    ForgotPasswordComponent,
    UserComponent,
    ViewComponent,
    CreatePasswordComponent,
    ToolbarComponent,
    SideNavComponent,
    DialogLoaderComponent,
    // DialogAddUserComponent,
    DialogChangeStatusComponent,
    DialogDeleteUserComponent,
    FilterComponent,
    CandidateListComponent,
    CandidateFiltersComponent,
    LoaderDownloadComponent,
    AdvancedFiltersComponent,
    ProjectAddComponent,
    ProjectListComponent,
    LoaderComponent,
    ErrorComponent,
    SuccessComponent,
    ConfirmationComponent,
    AgoPipe,
    TimeAgoPipe,
    MoveProjectComponent,
    RemoveApplicantComponent,
    InterviewListComponent,
    MoveInterviewComponent,
    InterviewStatusComponent,
    HrComponent,
    AssignHrComponent,
    LoiComponent,
    OfferLetterComponent,
    FinalStepComponent,
    FeedbackComponent,
    InterviewFeedbackShowComponent,
    InterviewerProfileComponent,
    AddInterviewerComponent,
    RecruitmentSummaryFiltersComponent,
    // InterviewRoundTwoComponent,
    // InterviewRoundTwoFeedbackComponent,
    // InterviewRoundTwoFeedbackShowComponent,
    SideNavLatestComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    JobPostingComponent,
    JobPostingCreateComponent,
    AssignProjectComponent,
    NodataComponent,
    ScreeningComponent,
    EngagedViewComponent,
    RejectLoiComponent,
    MoveApplicantComponent,
    DialogExampleComponent,
    MakeJobLiveComponent,
    VerifyDocumentsComponent,
    CheckDocumentsComponent,
    SuggestOfferComponent,
    AddUserComponent,
    EditUserComponent,
    //AppraisalProgressComponent,
    //UpdateEmpMappingComponent,
    BottomSheetComponent,
    //ScheduleMeetingComponent,
    //EmployeeSefComponent,
    //AppraisalIssueShowComponent,
    //SefFeedbackFormComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatRadioModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatSlideToggleModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatProgressBarModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatSnackBarModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    MatSortModule,
    MatTableModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    MatListModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
    MatGridListModule,
    MatSlideToggleModule,
    MatChipsModule,
    MatExpansionModule,
    MatAutocompleteModule,
    MatStepperModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    MatDividerModule,
    MatTooltipModule,
    NgxMatSelectSearchModule,
    NgxMaterialTimepickerModule,
    MatRippleModule,
    CKEditorModule,
    CarouselModule,
    DragDropModule,
    // ChartsModule,
    // AppraisalModule
  ],
  providers: [
    AuthService,
    SensitiveService,
    ErrorService,
    UserService,
    AuthGuard,
    ExcelService,
    ProjectService,
    CandidateService,
    InterviewService,
    HrService,
    Title,
    // ThemeService,
    {
      multi: true,
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: KickoffService,
    }
  ],
  entryComponents: [
    // DialogAddUserComponent,
    DialogDeleteUserComponent,
    DialogLoaderComponent,
    LoaderDownloadComponent,
    LoaderComponent,
    ErrorComponent,
    SuccessComponent,
    ConfirmationComponent,
    RejectLoiComponent,
    MoveProjectComponent,
    MoveApplicantComponent,
    RemoveApplicantComponent,
    MoveInterviewComponent,
    InterviewStatusComponent,
    AssignHrComponent,
    LoiComponent,
    OfferLetterComponent,
    FinalStepComponent,
    InterviewFeedbackShowComponent,
    AssignProjectComponent,
    EngagedViewComponent,
    DialogExampleComponent,
    MakeJobLiveComponent,
    VerifyDocumentsComponent,
    SuggestOfferComponent,
    DialogChangeStatusComponent,
    //UpdateEmpMappingComponent,
    BottomSheetComponent,
    //AppraisalProgressComponent,
    //ScheduleMeetingComponent,
    //EmployeeSefComponent,
    //AppraisalIssueShowComponent,
    //SefFeedbackFormComponent
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

The feature module --

**AppraisalModule**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { AppraisalRoutingModule } from '../yearly-appraisal/appraisal-module-routing.module';
import { AppraisalComponent } from '../yearly-appraisal/appraisal/appraisal.component';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
// import { MatStepperModule } from '@angular/material/stepper';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatCheckboxModule } from '@angular/material/checkbox';
import { MatDatepickerModule } from '@angular/material/datepicker';
import { MatRadioModule } from '@angular/material/radio';
import { MatSelectModule } from '@angular/material/select';
import { MatSlideToggleModule } from '@angular/material/slide-toggle';
import { MatMenuModule } from '@angular/material/menu';
// import { MatSidenavModule } from '@angular/material/sidenav';
// import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material/toolbar';
import { MatCardModule } from '@angular/material/card';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
// import { MatProgressBarModule } from '@angular/material/progress-bar';
import { MatDialogModule } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { MatSnackBarModule } from '@angular/material/snack-bar';
import { MatPaginatorModule } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { MatSortModule } from '@angular/material/sort';
import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material/table';
import { MatListModule } from '@angular/material/list';
import {
  MatNativeDateModule,
  MatAutocompleteModule
} from '@angular/material';
import { MatProgressSpinnerModule } from '@angular/material/progress-spinner';
import { MatGridListModule } from '@angular/material/grid-list';
import { MatChipsModule } from '@angular/material/chips';
import { MatExpansionModule } from '@angular/material/expansion';
import { MatTabsModule } from '@angular/material/tabs';

import { MatDividerModule } from '@angular/material/divider';
import { MatTooltipModule } from '@angular/material/tooltip';

import { NgxMatSelectSearchModule } from 'ngx-mat-select-search';
import { NgxMaterialTimepickerModule } from 'ngx-material-timepicker';
import { MatRippleModule } from '@angular/material/core';
import { CKEditorModule } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular';
import { CarouselModule } from 'ngx-owl-carousel-o';
import { DragDropModule } from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';
import { ChartsModule } from 'ng2-charts';
import { DeactivateEmpAppraisalComponent } from '../../dialogs/deactivate-emp-appraisal/deactivate-emp-appraisal.component';
import { UpdateEmpMappingComponent } from '../../dialogs/update-emp-mapping/update-emp-mapping.component';
import { ScheduleMeetingComponent } from '../../dialogs/schedule-meeting/schedule-meeting.component';
import { AppraisalIssueShowComponent } from '../../dialogs/appraisal-issue-show/appraisal-issue-show.component';
import { EmployeeSefComponent } from '../../dialogs/employee-sef/employee-sef.component';
import { SefFeedbackFormComponent } from '../../dialogs/sef-feedback-form/sef-feedback-form.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppraisalComponent,
    DeactivateEmpAppraisalComponent,
    UpdateEmpMappingComponent,
    ScheduleMeetingComponent,
    AppraisalIssueShowComponent,
    EmployeeSefComponent,
    SefFeedbackFormComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    AppraisalRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatRadioModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatSlideToggleModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    // MatSidenavModule,
    // MatToolbarModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatIconModule,
    // MatProgressBarModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatSnackBarModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    MatSortModule,
    MatTableModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    MatListModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
    MatGridListModule,
    MatSlideToggleModule,
    MatChipsModule,
    MatExpansionModule,
    MatAutocompleteModule,
    // MatStepperModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    MatDividerModule,
    MatTooltipModule,
    NgxMatSelectSearchModule,
    NgxMaterialTimepickerModule,
    MatRippleModule,
    CKEditorModule,
    CarouselModule,
    DragDropModule,
    ChartsModule
  ],
  entryComponents: [
    DeactivateEmpAppraisalComponent,
    UpdateEmpMappingComponent,
    ScheduleMeetingComponent,
    AppraisalIssueShowComponent,
    EmployeeSefComponent,
    SefFeedbackFormComponent
  ]
})

export class AppraisalModule { }
```

**ProtocolService**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  HttpClient,
  HttpHeaders,
  HttpParams
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { IVerifyTokenSuccess } from '../interfaces/i-response';
import { API_URL } from '../app.constant';
// import { SensitiveService } from './sensitive.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from '../auth.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProtocolService {

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private auth: AuthService,
    private router: Router
  ) { }

  async checkHandShake() {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders()
      .set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    const body: HttpParams = new HttpParams();
    const response = await this.http.post(`${API_URL}user/verifytoken`, body.toString(), { headers })
      .toPromise()
      .then((res:any) => {
        // console.log(res);
        this.auth.confirmUser(res.result.userinfo);
        if (this.router.url === '/user') {
          if (res.result.userinfo.super_admin !== '1') {
            this.router.navigate(['/view']);
            return res.valid as boolean;
          }
        }
        return res.valid as boolean;
      }).catch((error: any) => {
        this.router.navigate(['/']);
        return false;
      });
    return response;
  }
}
```

**AuthGuard**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  CanActivate,
  ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  RouterStateSnapshot,
  Router,
} from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
// import { SensitiveService } from './services/sensitive.service';
import { ProtocolService } from './services/protocol.service';
import { IUser } from './interfaces/i-response';
import { map, take } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(
    private auth: AuthService,
    private router: Router,
    private _protocol: ProtocolService
  ) { }

  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    return this.auth.currentUser.pipe(
      take(1),
      map((user: IUser) => {
        if (!user) {
          this._protocol.checkHandShake();
        }
        return true;
        
      })
    );

    
  }
}
```

Comment: Since you have used `providedIn: 'root` you don't need to import array inside app module. Also from your given code it's not clear why it's being called twice? Please share the code or method from where you're calling your service method

Comment: This service is being called in `AuthGuard` because the purpose of this service is to verify the user info(which is declared in a separate class in app level and is checked with the user info from backend). If the user info matches with the info of the logged in user then only the page will show.

And #2 is my mistake. This service is not included in the providers array in `AppModule`.

I have added the code of `AuthGuard` in the question.